# Tensorflow Lite - Input shape must be 5 dimensional error

Tags: android, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to port a tensorflow model to tensorflow lite to use it in an android application. The conversion is successful and everything runs except for `Internal error: Failed to run on the given Interpreter: input must be 5-dimensional`. The input in the original model was `input_shape=(20, 320, 240, 1)`, which is 20 320 x 240 grayscale images (therefore ...,1). Here is the important code:

```
List<Mat> preprocessedFrames = preprocFrames(buf);
//has length of 20 -> no problem there (shouldn't affect dimensionality either...)

        int[] output = new int[2];
        float[][][] inputMatrices = new float[preprocessedFrames.toArray().length][320][240];

        for(int i = 0; i < preprocessedFrames.toArray().length; i++) {
            Mat inpRaw = preprocessedFrames.get(i);

            Bitmap data = Bitmap.createBitmap(inpRaw.cols(), inpRaw.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(inpRaw, data);

            int[][] pixels = pixelsFromBitmap(data);
            float[][] inputMatrix = inputMatrixFromIntPixels(pixels);
            // returns float[][] with floats from 0 to 1

            inputMatrices[i] = inputMatrix;
        }

        try{

            detector.run(inputMatrices, output);
            Debug("results: " + output.toString());
        }
```

The model gives me an output of 2 neurons translating into 2 labels.
The model code is the following:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(name='detector')
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=(56), input_shape=(20, 320, 240, 1), strides=(2,2,2), kernel_size=(3,11,11), padding='same', activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling3D(pool_size=(1,4,4)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=(72), kernel_size=(4,7,7), strides=(1,2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=(81), kernel_size=(2,4,4), strides=(2,2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=(100), kernel_size=(1,2,2), strides=(3,2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=(128), kernel_size=(1,2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(768, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.011)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.012)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001), loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=['accuracy'])
```

EDIT: I printed out the first input tensor as follows:

```
int[] shape = detector.getInputTensor(0).shape();
            for(int r = 0; r < shape.length; r++){
                Log.d("********" + r, "*******: " + r + " : " + shape[r]);
            }
```

With that I  first get the output [1,20,320,240,1]and after that I only get [20,320,240]. I am really quite desperate now...

Comment: Hi. Have you printed input and output tensor shapes of interpreter after loading it?

Comment: I updated the post with the input shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out by myself and it seems like I really only had to make the input 5 dimensional by putting the content into a first dimension and every single pixel into a fifth dimension. I don't know why, but I will accept that xD.

```
float[][] output = new float[1][2];
            float[][][][][] inputMatrices = new float[1][preprocessedFrames.toArray().length][320][240][1];

            for(int i = 0; i < preprocessedFrames.toArray().length; i++) {
                Mat inpRaw = preprocessedFrames.get(i);

                Bitmap data = Bitmap.createBitmap(inpRaw.cols(), inpRaw.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Utils.matToBitmap(inpRaw, data);

                int[][] pixels = pixelsFromBitmap(data);
                float[][] inputMatrix = inputMatrixFromIntPixels(pixels);

                for (int j = 0; j < inputMatrix.length - 1; j++) {
                    for(int k = 0; k < inputMatrix[0].length - 1; k++) {
                        inputMatrices[0][i][k][j][0] = inputMatrix[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
```